# Django 1.8 No module named front

Tags: python, django

Here is my project folder structure.

```
<pre>
front
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── manage.py
├── middleware.py
├── settings.py
├── news
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin_views.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── search_indexes.py
│   ├── search_sites.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   ├── views.py
</pre>
```

After I run

```
./manage.py runserver
```

then I visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/

It gives me error:

```
No module named front
```

This is caused by the following line in file views.py under news folder.

```
from front import settings
```

So the front folder is one level up to the views.py file. How I import the settings from one level up folder?

Thanks!

Comment: Try importing variables from settings rather than importing whole settings. `from front.settings import variable`. Also configure your environment to use project settings.

Comment: Use `from django.conf import settings` to access to any settings variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either way this is wrong, whenever you're importing your own settings you should be importing from `django.conf`

```
from django.conf import settings
```

This isn't a module, its an object that does magic to import any settings you have set in your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code):

> Also note that your code should not import from either global_settings or your own settings file. django.conf.settings abstracts the concepts of default settings and site-specific settings; it presents a single interface. It also decouples the code that uses settings from the location of your settings.